# basic strings and variables python

Tags: python, string, variables

Write a function, called introduction(name, school) that takes, as input, a name (as a string) and a school, and returns the following text: “Hello. My name is name. I have always wanted to go to school.”

This is my code

```
def introduction("name","school"):
    return ("Hello.  My name is ") + str(name) + (".  I have always wanted to go to The") + str(school) + (".")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 5, in <module>
invalid syntax: None, line 5, pos 23
```

Answer (score 7):

```
def introduction("name","school"):
```

should be

```
def introduction(name,school):
```

The names you provide as the formal parameters of the function are essentially variables that the values of the actual parameters get assigned to. Including a literal value (like a string) wouldn't make much sense.

When you call or invoke the function, that is where you provide a real value (like a literal string)

```
def introduction(name,school):
    return ("Hello.  My name is ") + str(name) + (".  I have always wanted to go to The") + str(school) + (".")

print introduction("Brian","MIT")
```

Comment: I'm still not following you.  I am a beginner in programming as you can tell.  What code would work than? it is still coming up with an error with parenthesis.

Comment: My answer now includes the entire code (updated) as the last piece. Copy-paste that and it should run. You can change "Brian" to "ryan" and "MIT" to "iowa".

Comment: The `def introduction(name,school):` part creates a function, but doesn't actually execute it. The `print introduction("Brian","MIT")` part actually executes the function with the values "Brian" and "MIT".

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the function should take variables and not strings. When you declare, "introduction("name","school"):", that is what you are doing. Try this:

```
def introduction(name, school):
```

Here:

```
>>> def introduction(name, school):
...     return ("Hello.  My name is ") + str(name) + (".  I have always wanted to go to The") + str(school) + (".")
...
>>> print introduction("Sulley", "MU")
Hello.  My name is Sulley.  I have always wanted to go to TheMU.
>>>
```

Comment: I did do that but came up with error:                         introduction(ryan, iowa)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
NameError: name 'ryan' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the function are variable names, not string constants, and therefore should not be in quotes. Also, the parentheses around the string constants and the conversions of the arguments to strings in the return statement are not necessary.

```
def introduction (name,school):
    return "Hello. My name is " + name + ". I have always wanted to go to " + school + "."
```

Now, if you call the function like `print(introduction("Seth","a really good steak place")) # Strange name for a school...` then the arguments you're calling the function with *are* string constants and so these you *should* put in quotes.

Of course, that doesn't apply if the arguments aren't constants...

```
myname = "Seth"
myschool = "a really good steak place" # Strange name for a school...
print(introduction(myname,myschool))
```

...and so you are instead providing the variables `myname` and `myschool` to the function.

Comment: it is still coming up with an error saying the name is not defined